# How to speed up multiple vector convolution in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vector, convolution

I'm having a problem with finding a faster way to convolve multiple vectors. All the vectors have the same length M, so these vectors can be combined as a matrix (`A`) with the size (`N`, `M`). `N` is the number of vectors.

Now I am using the below code to convolve all these vectors:

```
B=1;

for i=1:N

B=conv(B, A(i,:));

end
```

I found this piece of code becomes a speed-limit step in my program since it is frequently called. My question is, is there a way to make this calculation faster? Consider `M` is a small number (say 2).

Comment: How big is N?  If it's large (say 10000), then your B vector is growing over time which will also slow things down.

Comment: For my application, N usually is not very big (<100), but it is true that B is growing over time. I do not know yet how could pre-allocate space for B in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be quite a lot faster if you implement your convolution as multiplication in the frequency domain.

Look at the way `fftfilt` is implemented.  You can't get optimal performance using `fftfilt`, because you want to only convert back to time domain after all convolutions are complete, but it nicely illustrates the method.

Answer (score 1):

Convolution is associative.  Combine the small kernels, convolve once with the data.

Test data:

```
M = 2; N = 5; L = 100;
A = rand(N,M);
Bsrc = rand(1,L);
```

Reference (convolve each kernel with data):

```
B = Bsrc;
for i=1:N,
    B=conv(B, A(i,:));
end
```

Combined kernels:

```
A0 = 1;
for ii=1:N,
    A0 = conv(A0,A(ii,:));
end
B0 = conv(Bsrc,A0);
```

Compare:

```
>> max(abs(B-B0))
ans =
   2.2204e-16
```

If you perform this convolution often, precompute `A0` so you can just do one convolution (`B0 = conv(Bsrc,A0);`).

Comment: Good point. However, in my specific case, Bsrc is simply 1. It'd be really great if the inner loop calculation (A0 part) can be further speed up.

Comment: "All vectors have the same length" according to the question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. each vector has been put as a column of A. B is just being used for saving the convolution result and initialized to 1.

Comment: @Kanzy I think you mean each vector is a _row_ of `A`. But what would you do with `A0`, out of curiosity? Does `A` change frequently?

Comment: @chappjc Yes, A changes frequently. Each time I need to convolve all rows of A together. So there is no A0 in my original question.